# How can I apply Monotone convergence theorem to $\lim_{M\to\infty} \int_0^M$ case?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

In the book it says that by Monotone convergence theorem,

$$\lim_{M\to\infty}\int_0^M e^{-r} \, dr = 1
$$
for the Lebesgue integral case. But how can I apply Monotone convergence theorem to this case?

Comment: Is this not $\Gamma (1)$?

Comment: yes but my question is not that

Comment: This is a silly application of the MCT. You can evaluate the integral for each $M$ and easily find the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fact that

$$\int_0^M e^{-r} = \int \chi_{[0,M]}e^{-r}$$

Where $\chi_{[0,M]}$ is an indicator function. You can define a sequence of positive, increasing measurable functions $f_n = \chi_{[0,n]}e^{-r}$ so you can write $$\lim_{M\to\infty}\int_0^M e^{-r} =\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n$$

Hopefully you should see how the MCT applies here.

Comment: Thanks then can I understand the right integral $\int$ as $\int_{\mathbb R}$?

Comment: Yes, here $\int$ means $\int_{\mathbb R}$

Comment: Yes- it is useful in measure theory to think of all integrals as being over the entire measure space you are working in